Running ROS to on a RPi5 8GB with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop ver
I have my university robot project based on RP4B 8GB, but a few days ago I have bought the newest RPi (which is Raspberry Pi 5 8GB). I had already installed Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS. I have encountered an issue when I tried to install ROS2 Humble for my RPi5. Is there any way to install ROS2 on RPi5 with Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS without using Docker?
Thank you in advance!:slight_smile:

I think you will find it difficult, because ROS2 Humble is targeted at Ubuntu 22.04.  Is using 24.04 essential?

I've just tried to boot Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop ARM64 v8 version, but probably it's impossible (I'd even checked it out on different forums). Someone who is responsible for Ubuntu on RPi said that they have no plans to backport Pi 5 support to 22.04 LTS. I have RPi 4B 8GB and I just wanted to speed up my robot with new RPi 5 8GB. The only essential for me is to find a way to run Ubuntu withoud Docker to run ROS2. As I've heard, companies usually using ROS2 Humble. I wanna become a Robotics Eng and I wanna learn the most useful things. That`s it
